# Enviar Formulario sin boton submit en paypal

Tags: phpmyadmin, formularios, paypal

Buen día, tiene poco que estoy realizando programación (novato) pero tengo un problema.

tengo un formulario que debes llenar y sobre esta la informacion que llenas te arroja un resultado que es el costo que debes pagar via paypal, al aceptar el pago envia los datos recolectados del consol log de paypal y los manda a una base de datos, pero me falta agregar los datos del formulario. he tratado de integrar la funcion de enviar el formulario al boton de paypal pero se rompe el boton y deja de funciona.

hasta ahora lo que consigo es que solo se vayan los datos que me regresa la compra pero no logro jalar los datos del formulario para que suban juntos.

LO QUE YA INTENTE:
Logro conectar con la base de datos y enviar la informacion del formulario por medio del boton submit y funciona correctanmente, pero esta forma no sube los datos que regresa paypal de completado.

por otro lado logro subir a la misma base de datos la informacion que me regresa paypal pero sin la informacion de los input, me los manda en blanco y me arroja un mensaje de que las key de los input no son correctas.

en resumen puedo hacerlo por separado pero no junto, lo que quiero es que suba toda la informacion al mismo tiempo.

asi que recurro a ustedes para solicitar sugerencias de como en el mismo envio de datos de paypal integro los datos del formulario.

alguna sugerencia?

```js
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "pedidosmb";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conexion) {
    die("Error al conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Conectado correctamente";

/** insercion de datos capturados en formulario conexion correcta */

$date = $_POST["date"];
$Ciudad = $_POST["Ciudad"];
$DicOrg = $_POST["DicOrg"];
$CPOrg = $_POST["CPOrg"];
$DirDes = $_POST["DirDes"];
$CPDes = $_POST["CPDes"];
$larg = $_POST["larg"];
$anch = $_POST["anch"];
$alto = $_POST["alto"];
$peso = $_POST["cotiza"];
$telOrig = $_POST["TelRem"];
$telDes = $_POST["TelDes"];
$Electronico = $_POST["f10ab"];
$usName = $_POST["us10"];
$nameDestiny = $_POST["us20"];

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$datos = json_decode($json, true);

    
    $id_transaccion = $datos['detalles']['id'];
    $monto = $datos['detalles']['purchase_units'][0]['amount']['value'];
    $status = $datos['detalles']['status'];
    $fecha = $datos['detalles']['update_time'];
    $fecha_nueva = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fecha));
    
   

$sql= "INSERT INTO pedidosmb (city_serv, date_serv, origin_address, code_origin, destiny_address, code_destiny, larg, anch, alto, peso, phone_origin, phone_destiny, dic_elec, name_us, name_destiny, id_transaction, price, aceptation, fecha) VALUES ('$Ciudad', '$date', '$DicOrg', '$CPOrg', '$DirDes', '$CPDes', '$larg', '$anch', '$alto', '$peso', '$telOrig', '$telDes', '$Electronico', '$usName', '$nameDestiny', '$id_transaccion', '$monto', '$status', '$fecha_nueva')";

if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
    echo "Nuevo registro creado con exito";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
}
mysqli_close($conexion);




?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style_cot.css">
    <title>Cotizador_envios</title>
    
    
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ATCrqvL3n3pzvuQaeRLdoJ_c-16TFG-C45tXJGZCopFOuvbA7evDMnALSNZbFcP7DhjmF3Xpe3vJsYPe&currency=MXN"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Cotizador de Envíos</h1>

<form  action="PedidosMB.php" method="post" name="formAct" id="form01" class="formulario">
 
    <div>     
        <p>Seleccione la ciudad de Servcio</p>
        <select name="Ciudad" id="Ciudad" class="formulario" required>
            <option value="Opt">Seleccionar Ciudad</option>
            <option value="CDMX"class="formulario" >Ciudad de México</option>
            <option value="GDL"class="formulario">Guadalajara</option>
            <option value="MTY"class="formulario">Monterrey</option>
            <option value="PUE"class="formulario">Puebla, Pue.</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Fecha de Servicio</p> 
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="formulario" required>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Origen
        <input type="text" placeholder="Direccion de origen"class="formulario" name="DicOrg" id="DicOrg" required>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>C.P.
        <input type="number" placeholder="C.P. Origen" class="formulario" name="CPOrg" id="CPOrg" required>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Destino</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Direccion de Entrega"class="formulario" name="DirDes" id="DirDes" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>C.P.</p>
        <input type="number" placeholder="C.P. Destino" class="formulario" name="CPDes" id="CPDes" required>   
    </div>

    <div>
        <P>Dimenciones del Paquete (en cms).</P><br>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Largo (cms)" step="0.001" class="formulario" name="larg" id="larg" required><br>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Ancho (cms)" step="0.001" class="formulario" name="anch" id="anch" required><br>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Alto (cms)" step="0.001" class="formulario" name="alto" id="alto" required><br>
        <p>Peso del Paquete (en Kg)</p>
        <input id="cotiza" type="number" placeholder="ejem: 2.3" step="0.001" class="formulario" name="cotiza" required>
    </div>
    <p>
    <h2 style="text-align:center"> $ <span name="PrecioFinal" id="PrecioFinal" >0.00</span> </h2><br>
    </p> <br>
    <p>
    <summary style="text-align:center">Completa tu Servicio</summary>
    </p>   
        <div>
        <p>Remitente</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Remitente"class="formulario" name="us10" id="us10" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Telefono</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Numero a 10 digitos" class="formulario" name="TelRem" id="TelRem" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>E-mail</p>
        <input type="email" placeholder="e-mail" class="formulario" name="f10ab" id="f10ab" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Destinatario</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Destinatario"class="formulario" name="us20" id="us20" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Telefono</p>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Numero a 10 digitos" class="formulario" name="TelDes" id="TelDes" required>
    </div>
    <br>

    <button style="center" type="submit" class="button-70" role="button"> Ir a Pagar</button> <br>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox" required> Confirmo que la información para el servicio es correcta, he leído y acepto los terminos y condiciones.</label><br><br>

    <div type="submit" id="paypal-button-container" ></div>         


   

</form>


         
        
<script src="caldim.js"></script>
<script>

    
    function enviar_formulario() {
        document.formAct.submit();
        console.log(formAct);
    };
</script>

<script> 
paypal.Buttons({
        style:{
            color: 'blue',
            shape: 'pill',
        },
        createOrder: function(data,actions){
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: PrecioFinal
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions){
            let url = 'captura.php'
            actions.order.capture().then(function (detalles){
                /*window.location.href="paycomplet.html" */
                console.log(detalles)

                return fetch(url,{
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'aplication/jason'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        detalles: detalles
                    })
                })
            })
        },

        onCancel: function(data){
            alert("Pago Cancelado");
            console.log(data);
        },
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya que mencionas que has intentado algo sin lograr resultado positivo, sería de ayudar ver eso que has intentado(código) para que la comunidad de SOes te pueda ayudar. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por la observación, pense que lo habia agregado pero no.